# Convert unicode to string

Tags: python, json, unicode, python-2.x

I'm building a program which takes information from a Json file and then prints some of that data. However some of the data maybe using unicode characters. How can I convert this unicode string to just a plain string ignoring the unicode.

For example I could get a tweet:

```
@Hellblazer2014 Porto Alegre n\u00e3o pode fazer que nem Salvador que vetou o Uber , mas continua funcionando. \u00c9 imposs\u00edvel deter o futuro.
```

and if I try to print that I get an error because it can't convert the characters. I'd rather it just print off the code string like above. Is there anyway I could do this?

Comment: Since the string handling differs a lot: Python 2 or 3?

Comment: If this is coming from JSON, `json.load` should correctly decode it (unless it's malformed to begin with). We need more details on what you're doing exactly and what you need.

Comment: It's Python 2 sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
string.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore')
to ignore the Unicode character in the string.